# Why am I getting "Error: Request failed with status code 400" using Axios/GraphQL to update Shopify products?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, shopify, http-status-code-400

I am in the process of building a lambda function that will update shopify products that have a specified tag on them. At this point I just want to run it locally to ensure that the code works, but it's not working.

```
    const express = require('express');
    require('dotenv').config();
    const app = express();
    const axios = require('axios');
    const gql = require('graphql-tag');
    const { print } = require('graphql/language/printer')

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        next();
    });

    const url = 'https://store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json';

    const mutQuery = gql`
    mutation productVariantsBulkUpdate($variants: [ProductVariantsBulkInput!]!, $productId: ID!) {
      productVariantsBulkUpdate(productId: $productId, variants: $variants) {
        product {
          id
        }
        productVariants {
          id
          title
          price
        }
        userErrors {
          field
          message
        }
      }
    }
    `
    const printedQuery = print(mutQuery);

    const fetchIDs = () => {
     return axios({
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'shpat_TOKEN'
        },
        method: 'post',
        data: {
        query: `{
            products(query: "tag:'change me'", first: 10) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  title
                  variants(first: 10) {
                    edges {
                      node {
                        id
                        title
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }`,
        variables: {}
        },
        url: url
    }).then(response => {
        return response.data
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    }

    const savedata = async () => {
        const data = await fetchIDs();
        const PRICE = "70.01"
        const arrayLength = data.data.products.edges.length;
        var productArray = []
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            productArray[i] = data.data.products.edges[i].node.id;
            const varArrayLength = data.data.products.edges[i].node.variants.edges.length;
            var constructedVariables = {}
            let variantArray = []
            for (let k = 0; k < varArrayLength; k++) {
                var variantObject = {
                    "id": data.data.products.edges[i].node.variants.edges[k].node.id,
                    "price": PRICE
                }
                variantArray.push(variantObject);
            }
            constructedVariables = {
                "productId": productArray[i],
                "variants": variantArray
            }
            let queryVariables = JSON.stringify(constructedVariables, null, 4);
            
            console.log("query variables: ", queryVariables)
            console.log("mutation query: ", printedQuery)
                axios({
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'shpat_TOKEN'
                    },
                    method: 'post',
                    
                    data: {
                        query: printedQuery,
                        variables: queryVariables
                    },
                    url: url
                }).then(result => {
                    console.log("Prices have been updated!", JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 4))
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 4))
                })
            }
        }
        
    savedata();
```

And here is my console output:

```
query variables:  {
    "productId": "gid://shopify/Product/7663794749669",
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42606074757349",
            "price": "70.01"
        },
        {
            "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42606074790117",
            "price": "70.01"
        }
    ]
}
mutation query:  mutation productVariantsBulkUpdate($variants: [ProductVariantsBulkInput!]!, $productId: ID!) {
  productVariantsBulkUpdate(productId: $productId, variants: $variants) {
    product {
      id
    }
    productVariants {
      id
      title
      price
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n    at createError (/Users/trevor/Documents/shop/graphQL/GraphiQLexamples/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/Users/trevor/Documents/shop/graphQL/GraphiQLexamples/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/trevor/Documents/shop/graphQL/GraphiQLexamples/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:532:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1346:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "shpat_TOKEN",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.26.1",
            "Content-Length": 574
        },
        "method": "post",
        "data": "{\"query\":\"mutation productVariantsBulkUpdate($variants: [ProductVariantsBulkInput!]!, $productId: ID!) {\\n  productVariantsBulkUpdate(productId: $productId, variants: $variants) {\\n    product {\\n      id\\n    }\\n    productVariants {\\n      id\\n      title\\n      price\\n    }\\n    userErrors {\\n      field\\n      message\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\",\"variables\":\"{\\n    \\\"productId\\\": \\\"gid://shopify/Product/7663793078501\\\",\\n    \\\"variants\\\": [\\n        {\\n            \\\"id\\\": \\\"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42606072955109\\\",\\n            \\\"price\\\": \\\"70.01\\\"\\n        }\\n    ]\\n}\"}",
        "url": "https://shop.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json"
    },
    "status": 400
}
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n    at createError (/Users/trevor/Documents/shop/graphQL/GraphiQLexamples/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/Users/trevor/Documents/shop/graphQL/GraphiQLexamples/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/trevor/Documents/shop/graphQL/GraphiQLexamples/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:532:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1346:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "shpat_TOKEN",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.26.1",
            "Content-Length": 701
        },
        "method": "post",
        "data": "{\"query\":\"mutation productVariantsBulkUpdate($variants: [ProductVariantsBulkInput!]!, $productId: ID!) {\\n  productVariantsBulkUpdate(productId: $productId, variants: $variants) {\\n    product {\\n      id\\n    }\\n    productVariants {\\n      id\\n      title\\n      price\\n    }\\n    userErrors {\\n      field\\n      message\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\",\"variables\":\"{\\n    \\\"productId\\\": \\\"gid://shopify/Product/7663794749669\\\",\\n    \\\"variants\\\": [\\n        {\\n            \\\"id\\\": \\\"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42606074757349\\\",\\n            \\\"price\\\": \\\"70.01\\\"\\n        },\\n        {\\n            \\\"id\\\": \\\"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42606074790117\\\",\\n            \\\"price\\\": \\\"70.01\\\"\\n        }\\n    ]\\n}\"}",
        "url": "https://shop.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I'm fairly new to node/ shopify/ and graphQL so bear with me and thank you for your help!